# WPF Datagrid: MVVM friendly way to bind SelectedCells to my ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm using the WPF datagrid, and have SelectionUnit="Cell" and SelectionMode="Extended". I'm also trying to adhere to the MVVM principals as much as I can.

I need my ViewModel to keep track of the current SelectedCells.

Life would be easy if I could just Bind its SelectedCells property to my ViewModel. Oddly enough, SelectedCells is only raised once - when we first select any cell in the grid.

MS explains it here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/737117f4-6d20-4232-88cf-e52cc44d4431

Can anyone think of an MVVM-friendly approach to get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I realized my last answer was for SelectedItems instead of SelectedCells, so I wrote a complete attached property class to do data binding for multiple SelectedCells which works as follows:

```xml
<controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource list}"
                   SelectionMode="Extended"
                 behaviors:DataGridSelectedCellsBehavior.SelectedCells="{Binding Path=SelectedGridCellCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I have a working source code and a demo project of it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170406130551/http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/).

**Attached property behavior Code :**

```cs
public class DataGridSelectedCellsBehavior
{
    // Source : https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=datagridthemesfromsl
    // Credit to : T. Webster, https://stackoverflow.com/users/266457/t-webster

    public static IList<DataGridCellInfo> GetSelectedCells(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IList<DataGridCellInfo>)obj.GetValue(SelectedCellsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetSelectedCells(DependencyObject obj, IList<DataGridCellInfo> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedCellsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedCells", typeof(IList<DataGridCellInfo>), typeof(DataGridSelectedCellsBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedCellsChanged));

    static SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler GetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler)obj.GetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);
    }
    static void SetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj, SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty, value);
    }

    static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedHandlerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler", typeof(SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler), typeof(DataGridSelectedCellsBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    //d is MultiSelector (d as ListBox not supported)
    static void OnSelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (GetSelectionChangedHandler(d) != null)
            return;

        if (d is DataGrid)//DataGrid
        {
            DataGrid datagrid = d as DataGrid;
            SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;
            foreach (var selected in GetSelectedCells(d) as IList<DataGridCellInfo>)
                datagrid.SelectedCells.Add(selected);

            selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetSelectedCells(d, datagrid.SelectedCells);
            };
            SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
            datagrid.SelectedCellsChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
        }
        //else if (d is ListBox)
        //{
        //    ListBox listbox = d as ListBox;
        //    SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;

        //    selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
        //    {
        //        SetSelectedCells(d, listbox.SelectedCells);
        //    };
        //    SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
        //    listbox.SelectionChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
        //}
    }

}
```

**View Model Code :**

```cs
class DemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{  
    private IList<DataGridCellInfo> selectedGridCellCollection = new List<DataGridCellInfo>();
    public IList<DataGridCellInfo> SelectedGridCellCollection
    {
        get { return selectedGridCellCollection; }
        set
        {
            selectedGridCellCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: T.Webster's answer is good if you're using .NET4. 
Apparently, if you're using .NET3.5 and taking the DataGrid from the WPF toolkit there's probably no easy answer and you'll have to catch the SelectedCellsChanged event and manually get 'myGrid.SelectedCells' and pass it along to your ViewModel. I know it sounds lame but there's probably no other way....

Comment: I checked you grid its pretty good but its painfully slow if we have a checkbox selecting/ deselecting all columns at once

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the SelectedCells constantly data-binded, or just when the user hits the OK/Accept button? If you only need it at the end of whatever process the user is in you can bind the SelectedCells to the CommandParameter property of a Button, for example. The SelectedCells is an IList, and you know enough to just do a cast to whatever object type the selection actually is. The other option is messier, you can use an attached property, keeping the event-handling out of your Views. This attached property would handle either a ListBox or in your case a DataGrid (MultiSelector).

```
public class Attach 
{
    public static IList GetSelectedItems(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IList)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItems(DependencyObject obj, IList value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attach this property to expose the read-only SelectedItems property of a MultiSelector for data binding.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(Attach), new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<object>() as IList, OnSelectedItemsChanged));



    static SelectionChangedEventHandler GetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (SelectionChangedEventHandler)obj.GetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);
    }
    static void SetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj, SelectionChangedEventHandler value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty, value);
    }
    static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedHandlerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionChangedHandler", typeof(SelectionChangedEventHandler), typeof(Attach), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    //d is MultiSelector (d as ListBox not supported)
    static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (GetSelectionChangedHandler(d) != null)
            return;

        if (d is MultiSelector)//DataGrid
        {
            MultiSelector multiselector = d as MultiSelector;
            SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;
            foreach (var selected in GetSelectedItems(d) as IList)
                multiselector.SelectedItems.Add(selected);

            selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetSelectedItems(d, multiselector.SelectedItems);
            };
            SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
            multiselector.SelectionChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
        }
        else if (d is ListBox)
        {
            ListBox listbox = d as ListBox;
            SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;

            selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetSelectedItems(d, listbox.SelectedItems);
            };
            SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
            listbox.SelectionChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
        }}}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceList}"
              myControls:Attach.SelectedItems="{Binding Path=myMvvmSelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectionMode="Extended" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to synchronize the DataGrid.SelectedItems with the ViewModel. This might be very similar to SelectedCells.

Comment: Just to add a small info for other readers: The example is based on code-behind event handlers which update the ViewModel in the `SelectionChangedEvent`, not on data binding between a ViewModel property and the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property. Nonetheless useful if someone doesn't want to follow too strict MVVM rules.

Comment: Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) is a design pattern. Design patterns describe how objects are allowed to interact. But they don’t forbid aspects like code-behind. If you look how Binding or Behaviors work internally, then you see that they also call methods on ViewModels or Models. This is not forbidden by MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between perfect MVVM bindings and full event handler codebehinds there is the gray area of interactivity EventTriggers (see Blend SDK) :)
If you put an eventtrigger to the datagrid, and set to "SelectionChanged" and pass the eventargs to a command (use an EventToCommand actiontrigger) you could get the selected items from the eventargs hopefully...
Or use the multibinding as said in the MS thread :)

Comment: TDaver: It sounds like a good idea but oddly enough SelectionChanges isn't fired when a cell is selected and the DataGrid is set to SelectionMode=Cell as it does when a row is selected when SelectionMode="FullRow". It's weird but true.....

Comment: SelectionChanges or SelectionChanged?

Comment: Yeah and one more... Do you need the CELLS or the ITEMS contained in your VM? the first is not great MVVM, but the first only requires SelectedItems property not SelectedCells, and I believe the second gets raised every time a cell in a different row gets selected (since it's the same item if the cells are in the same row...)

Comment: I used this approach and it works pretty well with mvvm light and its the fastest way too.. Selecting delecting 10000 rows without a hitch!!