# How to get selection of DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" Binded to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatable

I only seem to be able to find solutions with ObservableCollections and autogenerate columns, but i dont have a fixed amount of columns. And that is why I use a DataTable for binding to the DataGrid. I Dunno if its possible to make make a nested collection binding somewhat like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<RowData> Rows { get; set;}
public Class RowData
{
   public String ColumnName {get; set;}  
   public ObservableCollection<CellModel> Cells { get; set;}
}
```

To a Datagrid.

I have tried to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771894/1805974), but the attached property does not update the Selected Cells, and i do believe its because i am using a DataTable. In case its not let me post some code.
What it does is basically showing excel sheets so therefore there its inside a tab.

```
 <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
                            Height="400" Width="700"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SheetTabs}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTab}">
                    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding SheetName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid  
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SheetData}"
                                SelectionUnit="Cell"
                                Behaviors:DataGridHelper.SelectedCells="{Binding Path=CellSelections,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                SelectionMode="Extended"
                                 LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"
                                RowHeaderWidth="30">

                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>
```

What is binded is a ObservableCollection of this class:

```
public class SheetViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string SheetName { get; set; }
    public DataTable SheetData { get; set; }
    private IList<DataGridCellInfo> _cellSelection;
    public IList<DataGridCellInfo> CellSelections {
        get
        {
            return _cellSelection;
        }
        set
        {
            _cellSelection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("CellSelections");
        }
    }

}
```

the attacked property i am using looks like this, its stolen from [here](http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/).

```
#region SelectedCells
    public static IList<DataGridCellInfo> GetSelectedCells(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IList<DataGridCellInfo>)obj.GetValue(SelectedCellsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetSelectedCells(DependencyObject obj, IList<DataGridCellInfo> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedCellsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedCells", typeof(IList<DataGridCellInfo>), typeof(DataGridHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedCellsChanged));
    static SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler GetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler)obj.GetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);
    }
    static void SetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj, SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty, value);
    }
    static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedHandlerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler", typeof(SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler), typeof(DataGridHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    //d is MultiSelector (d as ListBox not supported)
    static void OnSelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (GetSelectionChangedHandler(d) != null)
            return;

        if (d is DataGrid)//DataGrid
        {
            DataGrid datagrid = d as DataGrid;
            SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;
            foreach (var selected in GetSelectedCells(d) as IList<DataGridCellInfo>)
                datagrid.SelectedCells.Add(selected);

            selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetSelectedCells(d, datagrid.SelectedCells);
            };
            SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
            datagrid.SelectedCellsChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
        }
        //else if (d is ListBox)
        //{
        //    ListBox listbox = d as ListBox;
        //    SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;

        //    selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
        //    {
        //        SetSelectedCells(d, listbox.SelectedCells);
        //    };
        //    SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
        //    listbox.SelectionChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
        //}
    }
```

Edit:

I have noticed that the constructer for the attached behavior is only fired ones, eventho there should be 4 gridviews, 1 for each tab. So maybe to problem is something to do with how the tabs are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt realize it would never workbefore addind a new list to the bound item, the selections would work.

So basically its on the bound

```
Behaviors:DataGridHelper.SelectedCells="{Binding Path=CellSelections,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

in the view model i just needed to put a;

```
CellSelections = new List<DataGridCellInfo>();
```

Before the attached property would actually work.

I managed to create an Observable Collection with dynamic objects, lookup ExpandoObject, for doing that plenty of post on topic here og stackoverflow.