# How to bind specific cell in datatgrid (WPF)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, mvvm

I have 5 columns in my datagrid, and I need to just select a specific cell to bind my data. My datagrid row is fixed to 2 rows only.

Comment: So add a binding to only that data template? This question is unanswerable without more detail.

Comment: try to override cell template and bind some data to it

Comment: Looks like similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714758/wpf-datagrid-mvvm-friendly-way-to-bind-selectedcells-to-my-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there is a `DataTable` called `Data` in your view model bound to your `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
```

Binding a text block (or other controls) to the a specific index will work using the `DataTable.DefaultView` property and the index operators. Binding to the second row (index 1) and third row (index 2) will look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.DefaultView[1][2]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fruchtzwerg, I'll try. :)